# Show $G$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I am trying to show that $G$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ where $G$ is the set of all matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ (the set of all invertible 2x2 matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_5$) of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
m & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Starting with the inverse element I get:

$\begin{pmatrix}
m & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{m} & \frac{-b}{m} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Clearly the bottom row of this inverse matrix is of the form we desire, but I'm confused about the top row and the $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ condition.  Obviously when $m=1$ and $b=0$ this inverse belongs to the subgroup, but does this need to be satisfied for all possible values of $m$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ or is its existence with these values enough to satisfy the inverse condition of a subgroup?

Apologies if this is a dumb question and I've missed something obvious.

Comment: I think they mean for $m$ to be nonzero. Observe that the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ are invertible with respect to multiplication (use for example Bezout’s Lemma).

Comment: Yes, $m \neq 0$ as the matrices are invertible.

Comment: Since $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ is finite, you just need to prove that $G$ is closed under matrix multiplication, as it actually is being $\mathbb{Z}_5^\times$ a finite field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m,n\in \mathbb{Z}_5\setminus \{0\} \Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
m & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} n & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} mn & mc+b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\in G$, because $mn\in \mathbb{Z}_5\setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field.

So $\frac{1}{m}$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ is another element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$. For example, if $m=2$ then $\frac{1}{2}=3$. This is because $2 \cdot 3 = 6 \equiv 1$ modulo $5$. So you have that the inverses are all in $GL_2 (\mathbb{Z}_5)$. It is a bit confusing notation to write $\frac{1}{m}$ because it looks like you are working in $\mathbb{Q}$, but that is not what you mean. For $-\frac{b}{m}$, you can treat that as $(-1)*b*\frac{1}{m}$ so you just need to know that whenever $m$ is nonzero in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, it has a multiplicative inverse.

This also means you were missing the condition that $m \neq 0$ in the question.

Comment: @AlHusain sorry I thought the condition $m \neq 0$ went without saying, I have now edited the question to include this.  Thank you for that answer, I don't have much experience working in modulo and find it difficult.